# Drawing enhanced metafile with alpha channel using PlayEnhMetaFile

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm  trying to convert an enhanced metafile containing transparent regions to a 32 bit bitmap using only GDI functions. Is this possible getting correct alpha values?

The following leads to a 32 bit bitmap with the alpha value of each pixel set to 0:

First I create a memory DC with `CreateCompatibleDC(NULL)` and a `HBITMAP` with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` using the screen DC retrieved with `GetDC(NULL)`. (The latter produces a handle to a 32 bit bitmap.)

Then I select the created bitmap into the memory DC using `SelectObject`.

Finally I draw an enhanced metafile containing transparent regions into the memory DC using `PlayEnhMetaFile`.

Comment: Most GDI functions won't affect alpha at all. GDI wasn't designed with blending in mind, although some support was bolted on later.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad. I will have a look at GDI+ then.

Comment: @thorsten Did you find an answer for this?
I am stuck at the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with `PlayEnhMetaFile` but you can draw memory DCs with alpha channel with `AlphaBlend`

```
inline BOOL AlphaBlt(HDC hDC, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, HDC hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int cxSrc, int cySrc)
{
    static BLENDFUNCTION bf = {AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA};
    return AlphaBlend(hDC, x, y, cx, cy, hSrcDC, xSrc, ySrc, cxSrc, cySrc, bf);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are right. I already found out about AlphaBlend. Unfortunately I can't use it because it would require a bitmap having meaningful alpha values in the first place. Furthermore it seems to be broken in Windows 7 64 bit: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/34f16345-8b61-4427-b72a-64a42261fa1c/)